# How to repeat code based on number in cell in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, dynamic

I have a spreadsheet that I need to add X amount of lines to. The code below is what I currently have. I need to change this macro every time I need a different amount of lines.

I was wondering if I could write this macro so that it will produce X amount of lines, where X is the number the user puts in cell A1.

So, what code can I use the read the Cell A1? Then, how can I loop my code to continually add a row in at A10 X times.

```
Sub Insert_specific_rows()
Dim CurrentSheet As Object
    For Each CurrentSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets         
    CurrentSheet.Range("A10:A138").EntireRow.Insert
    Next CurrentSheet
End Sub
```

Additionally, is there a way to rewrite this code so that when it adds a new row, it also brings copies down all cells from B9 through Z9?

EDITED WITH SOLUTION ----

So thanks to all your help, here is the code I now have. However, I need to do this for up to 50,000 lines sometimes and it appears this code does it line by line. Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Maybe it needs to add all the rows, and then do one copy down of the formula?

updated formula:

```
Sub All_Lines_Add_Rows_Macro()
Dim CurrentSheet As Object
Dim numRows As Long
For Each CurrentSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    numRows = InputBox("How many lines is your CDM?", "Rows to Add") - 1
    Range("A10:Z10").ClearContents
    For i = 1 To numRows
        CurrentSheet.Range("A10").EntireRow.Insert
        CurrentSheet.Range("AA9:EY9").Copy
        CurrentSheet.Range("AA10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
    Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete

Next CurrentSheet
```

End Sub

I guess I leave the add lines in the 'For i' loop. Then after all the lines have been added, how can I copy down from A10 to (A10 + X - 1 rows)?

Comment: look at usedrange and fill down

Comment: You could add an `InputBox` to get the number. http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-inputbox/

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, you want to check the value of A1 on each sheet and add that many rows? Take a small modification to your code:

```
Sub Insert_specific_rows()
    Dim CurrentSheet As Object
    Dim numRows As Long
    For Each CurrentSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        numRows = CurrentSheet.Range("A1").Value
        CurrentSheet.Range("A10:AE10").Delete
        for i = 1 to numRows         
            CurrentSheet.Range("A10").EntireRow.Insert
        next i
        CurrentSheet.Range("B9:Z9").Copy
        CurrentSheet.Range("B10:B" & (9 + numRows)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        CurrentSheet.Rows(9).EntireRow.Delete
        CurrentSheet.Rows(9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next CurrentSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, this worked!

Now, before I add the rows, I want it to also clear out A10 through AE10.

Comment: & after adding these rows, I then want to delete out row A9. Should be easy, I just dont know the VBA code.

Comment: delete "Row" `A9` or cell `A9`?

Comment: I want to delete out the entire row at A9.

Basically I'm creating a template spreadsheet. Headers are rows A1-A8. First line of Data is A9. Last line of data is A10. 

I have the macro insert (X-1) lines betwen A9 and A10. Then I need to clear out the columns in A10 between A and AE.

Then delete out the entire original A9 row to only be left with the rows I added in and A10.

Comment: @Adrenalist Do the edits now fit what you were hoping for?

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your edits and all your help, Ive learned a lot. I have now edited my main comment. 

This macro is sometimes going to execute for 1000 to 50,000 times. It just took many minutes to do 240 lines.

Do you have suggestions on how to improve this to run faster?
i.e in the loop add all rows, and then outside of the loop just copy down all formulas only once? How can this be done?

Comment: @Adrenalist see if the new edit works for you. I may be misunderstanding what you are saying, but I think this should do it.

Comment: New edit wasnt working. But I found a way to insert the rows much faster, just am having an issue copying down. Thanks so much for your help, I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222804/dynamically-create-lines-and-then-fill-in-with-formulas-from-first-row

Comment: @Adrenalist for what it is worth, the code you posted there wasn't what I posted above. Either way, see comment on other question.